# Grepping Linux logs on the basis of source IP and user name

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, grep

I have a server logs which contains data like `sourceip="1.1.1.1"` and `username="aaaa"`. Need a command to grep the entire log file and Search for multiple logins from same IP address but with different usernames

OS is Centos and the logs looks like :

```
2020-06-22T07:46:04+01:00 srcip=1.1.1.1 user="abcdefg"
```

and I would like to have the username(s) tried by each IP.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/594383/edit) your post to add an actual excerpt from your logfile (with possibly anonymized IP adresses and user names) and the desired output. Also, please specify what OS flavor and version you are running, and what you already tried.

Comment: os is centos and the logs looks like : 2020-06-22T07:46:04+01:00 srcip=*.*.*.* user="abcdefg". and i would like to have the username(s) tried by each IP

Comment: As I said, please [**edit**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/594383/edit) your post to include that information; it is practically unreadable when only added as a comment.

Comment: original post has been edited

Answer (score 0):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

## File

```
$ cat file
2020-06-22T07:46:04+01:00 srcip=1.1.1.1 user="abcdefg"
2020-06-22T07:46:04+01:00 srcip=1.1.1.1 user="abcdefy"
2020-06-22T07:46:04+01:00 srcip=1.1.1.1 user="abcdefz"
2020-06-22T07:46:04+01:00 srcip=1.1.1.3 user="xxx"
```

## Command

```
perl -MRegexp::Common -lne '
    push @{ $h->{$1} }, $2 if /srcip=($RE{net}{IPv4})\s+user="(\w+)"/;
    END{print "$_=" . join " ", @{ $h->{$_}} for keys %$h}
' file
```

From a pipe:

```
zgrep srcip <log_file> |
    perl -MRegexp::Common -lne '
        push @{ $h->{$1} }, $2 if /srcip=($RE{net}{IPv4})\s+user="(\w+)"/;
        END{print "$_=" . join " ", @{ $h->{$_}} for keys %$h}
    '
```

## Output

```
1.1.1.3=xxx
1.1.1.1=abcdefg abcdefy abcdefz
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to do like :

zgrep srcip <log_file> | awk '{print $20}' | grep srcip

which gives output like :
srcip=1.1.1.1

what i want is an output like :
srcip=1.1.1.1 user=abcdef

Comment: Yes you can remove ending `file` name and pipe what you want instead, like : `zgrep  srcip <log_file> | perl '...'`. Check edited post

Comment: @Deepu if you have extra detail, please [add it to your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/594383/edit). Don't bury it in the comments where it won't be found by most readers